# How to get Request Body as JSON exactly as sent to my API?

Tags: java, jackson

I am using Spring Boot with Jackson and I'm working on Transaction logging. I am trying to capture the Request Body sent to me exactly as it was sent. The way I am converting the Object into the JSON is below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

@Autowired
private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder;
// I have a Bean for my Jackson config in the application setup class 
// and am using this class to ensure consistency between my logs and the output

public String objectToJson(){

     ObjectMapper mapper = objectMapperBuilder.build();
     return mapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody);
}
```

This works the majority of the time. It's only an issue on the classes where I am using JsonProperty like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

public class UserDTO {

     // Input Fields

     @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
     private String username;

     @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
     private String password;


      // Output Fields

      @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
      @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
      private LocalDateTime createdDate;

      @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
      @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
      private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
 }
```

The problem is that it's doing exactly what it's configured to do. I need to convert the Object Request Body into the JSON format while using the Write modifiers I specified since that's how it will come into my code.

Is there anyway that I can invert the mapping logic to satisfy this requirement?

```
 // @RequestBody -> Mapper Convert (Using Write Rules) -> String JSON
```

---

**Trying to Clarify**

When using **objectToJson** method above on the @RequestBody of type **UserDTO** as described above I am seeing the output like:

```
 {
 "createdDate": "2018-11-06 00:00:00",
 "updatedDate": "2018-11-06 00:00:00"
 }
```

When I want the output to include the entire object including the WRITE_ONLY fields like:

```
 {
 "username": "myUserName9",
 "password": "securepassword123",
 "createdDate": "2018-11-06 00:00:00",
 "updatedDate": "2018-11-06 00:00:00"
 }
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you convert the JSON to an object, and the object back to JSON if what you want is the original JSON? Use a Sring of a byte array for your RequestBody, and you'll get the original JSON.

Comment: I want to use the object in my logic and the RequestBody as a String for Transaction logging purposes. I am using Spring AOP to do the logging and it should be possible without me changing any of the existing REST controllers defined or internal business logic.

Comment: Then instead of using the ObjectMapper to transform the object back to JSON, use it to transform the original JSON string to the object. That way you get the original JSON as a String, and you also have the object.

Comment: How can I get the original JSON string from the Proceeding Join Point? Could you provide a snippet or example I can see?

Comment: I'm not talking about AOP here, and I'm not clear how that is relevant. You asked how *to capture the Request Body sent to me exactly as it was sent*. So my suggestion is: use `@RequestBody String theJsonExactlyAsItWasSent` instead of `@RequestBody UserDTO user`. And if you need to transform the JSON string to a UserDTO, then use `objectMapper.readValue(theJsonExactlyAsItWasSent, UserDTO.class)`.

Comment: I can’t change my RequestBody to String because people are using that API and it would break existing functionality.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Why would it? The people would continue to send exactly the same JSON to your API. The only difference is that instead of letting Spring transform the JSON string they sent to a UserDTO (thus losing the original JSON string), you would tell Spring to give you the JSON string they sent, unmodified, and you would transform it to a UserDTO yourself, the same way Spring would have done (but without losing the original JSON string).

Comment: I guess the service functionality wouldn't break that way, but the Swagger functionality would. Where the users can see the described object and create the JSON from the dynamically created UI.

Comment: I don't know. I don't use Swagger. I use Spring REST Docs to document my APIs. It keeps me in control and doesn't have this problem.